# prevent returned json being wrapped in { d:

Tags: c#, json, uwp, httpwebrequest, webmethod

Edit: I've managed to get it working by setting the WebMethod to a void rather than a string and then writing to the response manually:

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

I have a webmethod which returns a serialised json object, below is an example:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string PostDropDowns()
    {

        TestClass t = new TestClass()
        {
            abc = "this has been sent over",
            Strings = new List<string> { "fdfdfd", "fdfdfdf" }
        };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
        return json;
    }
```

The JSON text =

```
{"abc":"this has been sent over","Strings":["fdfdfd","fdfdfdf"]}
```

In my c# UWP application I am calling this webrequest

```
 public static void GetDropDowns(string address)
    {
        //create the HTTPWebRequest
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContinueTimeout = 20000;
        // request.Accept = "text/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";


        try
        {

            //get the response
            using (var response = request.GetResponseAsync().Result)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

                var dds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(responseFromServer);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //error handling in here

        }
    }
```

However, the json I am getting back looks like this:

```
{"d":"{\"abc\":\"this has been sent over\",\"Strings\":[\"fdfdfd\",\"fdfdfdf\"]}"}
```

So when deserialize back to my TestClass both Title and Strings are null.

How do I preve that d coming through or get round it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know that is by design. Can't you just work with it as is?

Comment: I suppose that's part of the question. How? It looks like it thinks it's of type d:

Comment: I think the reported duplicate covers it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already looked through that "duplicate". Anything else I've found on this has been dealt with in javascript / ajax and has things like result.d which I can neither access or see within C#.

Comment: Just refactor your test class so it matches the json schema or use custom json serializer and apply the proper attributes. Using web services means conforming to their response, not the other way around.

Comment: Ive managed to get it to work by setting the webmethod as void and putting the json into the response manually using HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json); Thanks